Large Referrer Blocklist - Show/Hide Content Using PHP
Some content on my website needs to be hidden if the referrer is any of the blacklisted domains. The following seems to be working, but the full list is 12,000+ domains. I'm guessing there is a more efficient method to do this (using php 8). Any thoughts on best way to approach this?
$referrerdomain = $_GET['referrer'];

$cosblacklist = $referrerdomain !== '' && $referrerdomain ==  "validcodes.net" || $referrerdomain == "coupons4shopping.org" || $referrerdomain == "us.buybuylife.com" || $referrerdomain == "couponsgo.org";

    //Show Hide content
    if ($cosblacklist){
        $showorhidecos = "hideme";
    } else {
        $showorhidecos = "showme";
    }

?>

<div class="<?php echo $showorhidecos; ?>">
    <p>Show stuff</p>
</div>


Put the list of domains in a database and query that database with the given referrer.

<?php
$blacklist = file('blacklist.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES | FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES);
$referrerdomain = $_GET['referrer'] ?? '';
$cosblacklist = in_array($referrerdomain, $blacklist);
$showorhidecos = $cosblacklist ? "hideme" : "showme";
?>
<div class="<?php echo $showorhidecos; ?>">
    <p>Show stuff</p>
</div>

